Why the probability density for a finite potential well is more inside the well compared to outside where potential is zero for higher value of $n$?

Can somebody explain to me why the probability density is higher in this case inside the barrier region when it should be more where the potential is less?! max(V) is 200 I've normalized it so that to represent alongside the wavefunction.

your graph is certainly not of a probability density since your function is not everywhere positive.

You  seem to have chosen  a resonant  energy where there is perfect transmission through the barrier. The  particle travels slower where the potential is higher, so the particle lingers there longer. In other words the current $\rho v$ is independent of position, so $\rho$ must be bigger where $v$ is smaller.

Looks like 1 dimension Mie Scattering.
